# from keras_contrib.layers import InstanceNormalization ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras_contrib

Tags: google-colaboratory

I can not find a solution to this problem:

```
    from keras_contrib.layers import InstanceNormalization
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras_contrib'
```

I tried to perform:

```
!pip install keras_contrib
```

Got a response:

```
Requirement already satisfied: keras_contrib in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras_contrib-2.0.8-py3.6.egg (2.0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: keras in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from keras_contrib) (2.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-preprocessing>=1.0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from keras->keras_contrib) (1.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from keras->keras_contrib) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.14 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from keras->keras_contrib) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from keras->keras_contrib) (3.13)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-applications>=1.0.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from keras->keras_contrib) (1.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from keras->keras_contrib) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from keras->keras_contrib) (1.14.6)
```

Tell me where to find a solution?
I use google colab.

Answer (score 2):

First install

`!pip install keras==2.3.1`

`!pip install git+https://www.github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib.git`

**then import**
`from keras_contrib.layers.normalization.instancenormalization import InstanceNormalization`

Answer (score 0):

This command may help you:

```
pip install git+https://www.github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib.git
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install keras_contrib using following commands.

1. `git clone https://www.github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib.git`
2. `cd keras-contrib`
3. `pip install git+https://www.github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib.git`